# Java-XPath to generate Parent-Child(s) structure

Tags: java, xpath

Following is the XML structure -

```
<Projects>
   <Project>
     <Name>Web Site Designing</Name>
     <Members>
        <MName>Jack</MName>
        <MName>John</MName>
        <MName>Jill</MName>
     </Members>
   </Project>
   <Project>
     <Name>Site Ranking</Name>
     <Members>
        <MName>Jack</MName>
        <MName>James</MName>
     </Members>
   </Project>
   <Project>
     <Name>E-Mailing</Name>
     <Members>
        <MName>Matt</MName>
     </Members>
   </Project>
<Projects>
```

What will be the XPath Query to get the following output in Java -

```
Web Site Designing,Jack,John,Jill
Site Ranking,Jack,James
E-Mailing,Matt
```

Right now the Java Code I am using is not doing the same. Pls find the java code below -

```
.......
.......
.......
String pName = "";
String mName = "";
Document doc = builder.parse("Project.xml");
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//Projects/Project");
Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("projInfo.txt"));
Node node;
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) 
{
    node = nodes.item(i);
    pName = xpath.evaluate("Name",node);
    mName = xpath.evaluate("Members/MName",node);

    //Here's something worng
    out.write(pName + "," + mName + "\r\n");
}
out.close();
.......
```

Have a nice day, JB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> mName = xpath.evaluate("Members/MName",node);

This returns a node-list, but in the next code line:

```
out.write(pName + "," + mName + "\r\n");
```

you are treating it as a single string.

It would be correct to process all nodes contained in `mName` iterating through `mName`.